# will logout failed when TGT expires on cas server, but session on client system is active

Tags: timeout, cas

1 cas client and 1 cas server.

cas client login success, then user use the client system over 2 hours, so the session never timeout on client system.

but cas server TGT may timeout, because TGT expires after 2 hours in inactivity.
then the user try logout the system. browser will send a logout request with TGT to cas server, 
but the TGT has already expires, so the logout will be failed, the cas server won't send logout request to the client 
system too, so the session in client system will still active.

is this a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Log out does not fail. When tgt expires on CAS, CAS will automatically reach out to client apps if u have SLO turned on